# Can you add an external function as a method in a React component class?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, refactoring, dry

Given the following React component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  sayGreeting = () => {
    return this.props.greeting;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.sayGreeting()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

`greeting` is passed via props and is just a string message. Given sayGreeting() might be used in multiple components, with the exact same definition, would it be possible to extract it into a file (see the following code) and then somehow include it in each component as needed. This is like the include module (or mixin?) pattern in programming languages like Ruby.

```
export const sayGreeting = () => {
  return this.props.greeting;
};
```

I was able to do it by importing sayGreeting from that file and setting the prototype of MyComponent as such:

```
import { sayGreeting } from './someFile';
// ...
MyComponent.prototype.sayGreeting = sayGreeting;
```

But the issue is the "this" keyword, so props will not be defined. I tried binding in the constructor using `this.sayGreeting = this.sayGreeting.bind(this)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You could always pass `props`, like `<div>{this.sayGreeting(props)}</div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [higher-order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html):

```
const myHOC = (composedComponent) => { 
  return class extends React.Component {
    sayGreeting = () => {
      return this.props.greeting;
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent sayGreeting={ this.sayGreeting } />;
    }
  };
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <div>{this.props.sayGreeting()}</div>
   }
}

export default MyHOC(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` into the function.

```
export const sayGreeting = ({props}) => {
  return props.greeting;
};
```

Then to use after importing:
`sayGreeting(this)`